# How to set up Google Analytics through Google Tag Manager for Next-Js?

Tags: google-tag-manager, next.js

formerly I was using react-ga npm module to insert google analytics in my next js app. and It was simply like this:

```
import ReactGA from 'react-ga'

export const initGA = () => {
  ReactGA.initialize('UA-*******-*', {
    titleCase: false
  })
}

export const logPageView = () => {
  if (window.location.href.split('?')[1]) {
    ReactGA.set({page: window.location.pathname + '?' + window.location.href.split('?')[1]})
    ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + '?' + window.location.href.split('?')[1])
  } else {
    ReactGA.set({page: window.location.pathname})
    ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname)
  }
}
```

and then I was calling logPageView function in my header(that was inserted to every page of my app) like this:

```
  componentDidMount () {
    if (!window.GA_INITIALIZED) {
      initGA()
      window.GA_INITIALIZED = true
    }
    logPageView()
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps () {
    if (!window.GA_INITIALIZED) {
      initGA()
      window.GA_INITIALIZED = true
    }
    logPageView()
  }
```

now I want to use Google Tag Manager to handle Analytics page view . How could I do this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In order to use Google Tag Manager you should inject your tag manager script on every page. since `_document.js` is the wrapper for every page, you should add the GTM script to `_document.js` in the head section like this:

```
<Head>
  <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
  })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-*****');`,
  }}>
  </script>
  ...
</Head>
```

Now you are all set to use Google Tag Manager in your next-js app. You should only proceed to handle pageview and other analytics related stuff from your GTM dashboard.

To set up google analytics pageview for single page applications(like nextjs) you can follow [these](http://tech.webinterpret.com/how-to-make-google-analytics-work-in-a-single-page-application-spa/#abetterway) steps.

Comment: "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" seems dangerous! can open you up to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack.

Comment: @MuhammadRiyaz it is not dangerous as long as you are sure the script is safe and in this case it is safe

Comment: You have way bigger problems than google analytics if someone manages to manipulate anything inside of dangerouslySetInnerHTML.

Comment: You also can add `.replace(/\n\s*/g, "")` to that text to remove newlines

Answer (score 28):

There is no need for any special library and some answers here look uncomplete. Just add the script to `<Head>` and noscript to `<body>` in _document.js

```js
import Head from 'next/document'  

<Head>
  <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: `(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
            new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
            'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
          })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');`}} />
</Head>
    
<body style={{ margin: 0 }}>
   <noscript dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `<iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXX"
        height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>`,
      }}
    />
    <Main />
    <NextScript />
</body>
```

Comment: You may want to import the Head component from `next/document` instead of `next/head`. 
 I.e. `import { Head } from 'next/document'`. According to nextjs [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document), they're not the same and the one from `next/document` is preferred for code that's common to all pages.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since this will allow nextjs to return the code in the HTML. `react-gtm-module` will inject it during the runtime using JavaScript so it will not work as expected

Answer (score 16):

Since you are using nextJS, there is no need to add pure javascript from Google Analytics, all you need to have is the GA tracking id.

Then you create util function:

```
export const event = ({ action, category, label, value }) => {
  window.gtag('event', action, {
    event_category: category,
    event_label: label,
    value: value
  })
}
```

and add this in your _document.js:

```
<script
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
  __html: `
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', '${GA_TRACKING_ID}');
`}}
/>
```

After that, you just need to import the util function in your page/ components and call:

```
gtag.event({
  action: 'submit_form',
  category: 'Contact',
  label: this.state.message
})
```

Reference: [example of NextJS with GA](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/master/examples/with-google-analytics)

Comment: Thank you. it's a great alternative.

Answer (score 12):

I found a better way of implementing it. We can use `react-gtm-module` library for it.

As Ryan Elainska mentions in their blog, [Google Tag Manager in Next.js](https://ryanelainska.com/blog/google-tag-manager-in-react) in the `_app.js` file of my NextJS installation:

```
import App, { Container } from 'next/app'
import React from 'react'
import './app.css'
import TagManager from 'react-gtm'

const tagManagerArgs = {
  id: 'GTM-XXXXXXX'
}

class MyApp extends App {
  componentDidMount () {
    TagManager.initialize(tagManagerArgs)
  }

  render () {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props
    return (
      <Container>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

export default MyApp
```

Comment: Thanks for the _app.js solution. As for the code, `'react-gtm'` should be `'react-gtm-module'`. It's wrong in the original source blog that was reposted here.

Comment: and `tagManagerArgs = { id: 'GTM-XXXXXXX' }` should be `tagManagerArgs = { gtmId: 'GTM-XXXXXXX' }`

Comment: This library doesn't work for me, it always returns 404

Answer (score 5):

Im using [react-gtm-module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-gtm-module) and config in `_app.js` inside `componentDidMount`

```
 componentDidMount() {
    const tagManagerArgs = {
      gtmId = 'GTM-00001'
    }

    TagManager.initialize(tagManagerArgs);
  }
```

this is my solution updated at Feb 11, 2020

Answer (score 3):

I'm using **redux** in my next.js application.

And this is pretty good solution if you're using redux:  **redux-beacon** +  **react-gtm-module**.

here is initialization code. This code can be triggered with hooks or componentDidMount in _app.js or with redux action if you're using redux.

```
const dataLayer = { ...your dataLayer config... }
const tagManagerArgs = {
  gtmId: process.env.GTM_ID,
  auth: process.env.GTM_AUTH,
  preview: process.env.GTM_PREVIEW,
  dataLayer
}
TagManager.initialize(tagManagerArgs)
```

below is middleware created with eventMap.

```
import { EventsMapper, createMiddleware } from 'redux-beacon'
import GoogleTagManager from '@redux-beacon/google-tag-manager'

const gtm = GoogleTagManager()

export const eventsMap: EventsMapper = action => {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return []
  }
}


export const gtmMiddleware = createMiddleware(eventsMap, gtm)
```

Answer (score 2):

Next.js since v11 [recommends](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-script-for-ga) using their [`<Script>`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script) tag, and the right place to add it is the [`App` component](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app).

`pages/_app.jsx`

```js
import React from 'react';
import Script from 'next/script';

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Script id="gtm" strategy="afterInteractive">
        {`
          (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
          new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
          j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
          'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
          })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXXX');
        `}
      </Script>
      <noscript>
        <iframe
          src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXX"
          height="0"
          width="0"
          style={{
            display: 'none',
            visibility: 'hidden',
          }}
        ></iframe>
      </noscript>

      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

You can see this solution working similarly for `gtag` in [nestjs-starter](https://github.com/thisismydesign/nestjs-starter) where I'm also setting the tag from an env var.

For v10 and lower use regular `<script>` tags according to [Google's guide](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/web#custom_web_installations).

Keep in mind that Google Analytics does automatic page tracking, but this will not work for every use case. For example, `hash` and `search` parameter changes are [not tracked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73362255/2771889). This can lead to a lot of confusion. For example, when using [`HashRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/hash-router) or anchor links the navigation will not be tracked. To have full control over page view tracking you can [disable automatic tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/pages#disable_pageview_measurement). See for a detailed explanation: [The Ultimate Guide to Google Analytics (UA & GA4) on React (Or Anything Else](https://csaba-apagyi.medium.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-google-analytics-ua-ga4-on-react-or-anything-else-ec9dc84c0211)

Manual page tracking: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63249329/2771889

Answer (score 2):

I recommend an OSS library `nextjs-google-analytics` as documented in [github](https://github.com/MauricioRobayo/nextjs-google-analytics) and published in [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nextjs-google-analytics). Its `<GoogleAnalytics/>` component is a wrapper of the NextJS' `<Script/>` as mentioned in other answers with additional features such as `trackPageViews` props which automatically track visitor route changes. It's a small library but IMO makes your codebase neat.

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but I recently wrote about this and detailed 2 solutions here: https://morganfeeney.com/how-to/integrate-google-tag-manager-with-next-js.

Prior to Next.js v11.0.0 the simplest way to do this was by using the custom _document.

Add the GTM script like this in a custom _document: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document

```js
import Head from 'next/document';
...

<Head>
  <script
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
      __html: `(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
      new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
      j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
      'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
      })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');`,
    }}
  />
</Head>

<body>
  <Main />
  <NextScript />
  <noscript
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
      __html: `<iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXX" height="0" width="0" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;" />`,
    }}
  />
</body>
```

**But how do you track page views??**

`window.onLoad` will not fire when navigating using client-side routing, so even though you add the script, it's not doing what you expect it to.

My preferred method is to use a function like this:

```js
export const gtmVirtualPageView = (rest) => {
  window.dataLayer?.push({
    event: 'VirtualPageView',
    ...rest,
  });
};
```

Then in _app.tsx add the following config:

```js
import '../styles/globals.css';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { gtmVirtualPageView } from '../lib/gtm';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const router = useRouter()

  useEffect(() => {
    const mainDataLayer = {
      pageTypeName: pageProps.page || null,
      url: router.pathname,
    };

    window.onload = () => window.dataLayer?.push({...mainDataLayer});

    gtmVirtualPageView(mainDataLayer);

  }, [pageProps])

  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

This allows for passing data via `pageProps` into the dataLayer.

Answer (score 0):

To use Google Tag Manager in your next js app you should inject your tag manager script on every page. You can do this by creating a _document.js in your pages folder of that project and you have to edit your _app.js to use Google Tag Manager. Here is my _app.js code you can follow this:

```js
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const router = useRouter()
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleRouteChange = (url) => {
      gtag.pageview(url)
    }
    router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange)
    router.events.on('hashChangeComplete', handleRouteChange)
    return () => {
      router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange)
      router.events.off('hashChangeComplete', handleRouteChange)
    }
  }, [router.events])

  return (
    <>
      {/* Global Site Tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics */}
      <Script
        strategy="afterInteractive"
        src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${gtag.GA_TRACKING_ID}`}
      />
      <Script
        id="gtag-init"
        strategy="afterInteractive"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag('js', new Date());
            gtag('config', '${gtag.GA_TRACKING_ID}', {
              page_path: window.location.pathname,
            });
          `,
        }}
      />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Here is _document.js:

```js
export default function Document() {
    return (
        <Html lang='en'>
            <Head>
                {/* Global Site Tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics */}
                <script
                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                        __html: `
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag('js', new Date());
          `,
                    }}
                />
            </Head>
            <body>
                <Main />
                <NextScript />
            </body>
        </Html>
    )
}
```

Create a gtag.js:

```js
export const GA_TRACKING_ID = '**********'

// https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/pages
export const pageview = (url) => {
    window.gtag('config', GA_TRACKING_ID, {
        page_path: url,
    })
}

// https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events
export const event = ({ action, category, label, value }) => {
    window.gtag('event', action, {
        event_category: category,
        event_label: label,
        value: value,
    })
}
```