# Next js and google analytics not working behind nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, next.js, google-analytics-4

I run my website on a server that reverse proxies all requests to a nextjs server and google analytics does not work behind this proxy.  I followed [this implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65081431/13558344) and everything works as intended when I run it on my own machine. The only reason that I can think that this doesn't work is because of the reverse proxy. I would like to still be able to implement google analytics via nextjs instead of adding it to the nginx config so that its easier to maintain. How can I make nextjs able to call google analytics when behind a proxy?

Answer (score 2):

After some simple debugging that I somehow forgot to do before hand I figured out the problem, or so I think. I had my G-Tag stored in an ENV var and I found out that you need to build and start the server with the ENV vars already set before running it. Previously I had, Built -> Added the ENV vars -> Started the server. This was **NOT** a problem with nginx or google analytics, or really even nextjs.