# How to set up Google Analytics 4 for React-Router?

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, react-router

I'm trying to set up Google Analytics 4 on my react site. Previously I used react-ga, but this library doesn't support Google Analytics 4 yet. I pasted the GA4 tag directly into the index.html file without an external library. What additional code do I need to add to get GA4 to work with react router?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can call `gtag` directly. Just put the global site tag code in your index.html `<head>`.

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXXXXX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXXXX');
</script>
```

I was facing the same issue today and ended up pulling out the react-ga package and going this route. I saved the [withTracker.js](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga/blob/master/demo/app/withTracker.jsx) piece from the react-ga demo code and modified it like below.

```
export default function withTracker(WrappedComponent, options = {}) {
    const trackPage = (page) => {
        window.gtag('send', 'page_view', {
            page_location: window.location.href,
            page_path: window.location.pathname            
        });
    };
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also checkout the npm package **ga-4-react**:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ga-4-react

Answer (score 0):

You should be able stop using react-ga and just insert the global script tag in index.html as Cameron mentioned. Keep in mind you'll likely need to ensure that your app is updating **both the window.location and document.title for GA4 work** as desired.

[Google's docs](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11403294?hl=en) mention:

> "When a pageview is sent to Analytics, the default page parameter values are used, unless modified. This means you do not need to modify page_title or page_location parameters if updates to window.location (e.g. via the History API) and document.title are made prior to the event being sent.".

I have a simple single page application and wasn't receiving detailed page view data until I updated the title AND location at each render.

Comment: What did you have to do to update the title and location?

Answer (score 0):

Background: There are 2 types of Google Analytics properties: Universal Analytics (`UA-xxxxxxxxx-x`) which is [deprecated with the end of life on 2023.07.01](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11583528?hl=en) and Google Analytics 4 property (`G-xxxxxxxxxx`) which is the replacement.

The simplest way to get started is to follow [Google's guide](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/install): include `gtag` on the page and use it as `window.gtag`. This method works for both old and new tags and there's even TypeScript support via `@types/gtag.js`. The script can be loaded async [as recommended](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs#alternative_async_tag).

`index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- ... -->

    <script
      async
      src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-xxxxxxxxxx" >
    </script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());
      gtag('config', 'G-xxxxxxxxxx')
    </script>

    <!-- ... -->
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- ... -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Keep in mind that Google Analytics does automatic page tracking, but this will not work for every use case. For example, `hash` and `search` parameter changes are [not tracked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73362255/2771889). This can lead to a lot of confusion. For example, when using [`HashRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/hash-router) or anchor links the navigation will not be tracked. To have full control over page view tracking you can [disable automatic tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/pages#disable_pageview_measurement). See for a detailed explanation: [The Ultimate Guide to Google Analytics (UA & GA4) on React (Or Anything Else](https://csaba-apagyi.medium.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-google-analytics-ua-ga4-on-react-or-anything-else-ec9dc84c0211)

Manual page tracking: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63249329/2771889

You can see this working in [cra-typescript-starter](https://github.com/thisismydesign/cra-typescript-starter) where I'm also setting the tag from an env var.

Answer (score -1):

No additional code is needed, just paste that tag into the index.html and Google Analytics will track all your urls.