# Google Analytics 4 doesn't send `page_view` on virtual page views (`historyChange` event for `hashchange` source)

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I added Google Analytics 4 to a React project via [script tags](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/install) in `index.html`. [Enhanced measurements](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9216061) are enabled and [virtual page views](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11403294?hl=en) should be tracked automatically.

[image]

`page_view` events are registered correctly on the dashboard when opening or reloading the page.

However, there are no `page_view` events fired on virtual page views. I.e. using `HashRouter` of React Router, that modifies `location.hash`.

In [debug mode](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7201382?hl=en) I do see the processing of the `historyChange` event, but no event is sent as a result:

```
Processing commands (1)
js?id=G-*********:165 Processing data layer push: {event: "gtm.historyChange-v2", gtm.historyChangeSource: "hashchange", gtm.oldUrlFragment: "/legal", gtm.newUrlFragment: "/", gtm.oldHistoryState: null, gtm.newHistoryState: null, gtm.oldUrl: "http://localhost:3000/", gtm.newUrl: "http://localhost:3000/", gtm.triggers: "8"}
```

I know I can manually send `page_view` events, but I'd love to understand how to make this work out of the box.

Project with this setup at [cra-typescript-starter@a91a6be97f3693f42289d41209e5d0273de02ee5](https://github.com/thisismydesign/cra-typescript-starter/tree/a91a6be97f3693f42289d41209e5d0273de02ee5)

Comment: Can you share about the screenshot of the history change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this happens with `HashRouter` because `gtag` ignores the hash part of the URL. Can't find this mentioned in the docs but it seems so from my testing and there are other mentions of this behavior: [1](https://support.google.com/analytics/thread/20971249?hl=en&msgid=21281508), [2](https://measureschool.com/track-single-page-applications-gtm/)